# Is there a way to stop terminal from saving commands?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command-history

Well, the thing I'm tired of clearing my terminal history again and again. So I was wondering if there's a way that the terminal doesn't record your history or the commands you've used.

If not, is there any way to do that?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Note: I use this command to clear terminal history:

```
cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history && history -c && exit
```

Comment: What do you mean by `clearing my terminal history`? Why don't you want to have a history?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk In our office our account get audited, I sometime install tweaks and run some other commands which may be considered as unofficial, sometimes I forget to clear history. In this scenario, I need if there's alternative for it.

Comment: Won't the lack of terminal history be suspicious?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Single commands can be omitted from history (and `up`/`down` recall) by prepending with a space:

```
$ echo "foo"  # saved
$  echo "bar" # <-- not saved
```

Otherwise, you can turn off history by adding to `~/.bashrc`:

```
set +o history
```

(to reenable, use `set -o history`)

If you want to disable it for the current session only:

```
$ unset HISTFILE
```

Comment: There's also some information here: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/7041/dont-save-commands-in-bash-history-only-for-current-session
This is an extension to @bertieb 's post above ('$ unset HISTFILE').  They are current session only changes.

Comment: `Single commands can be omitted from history (and up/down recall) by prepending with a space` - only if `$HISTCONTROL` contains `ignorespace`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk or $HISTCONTROL contains `ignoreboth`, which 14.04 has set by default :)

Answer (score 3):

Although this has been answered, I think this is also worth noting - if you wanted to, you could remove your `.bash_history` file, and add a symlink with the same name pointing to `/dev/null`. That would produce the same results - in fact, this solution is shell-agnostic (as long as you target the correct history file.

All you need is this:

```
ln -s /dev/null ~/.bash_history
```

Just don't do something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/435887) and you'll be fine.

Comment: Oh my, that askubuntu question is so awkward, it hurts. (Upvoted your answer because using a symlink is a different approach that doesn't require one to edit login profile files.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends from the shell you are using. From the command you give it seems you are working with a *bash shell*. In this case you can both use

```
HISTSIZE=0
```

or

```
HISTFILE=
```

With the first one (`HISTSIZE=`) you put to zero the size of the *history* for the current shell. This means that after this command you will have no answer from `history` or pushing <kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>... You can use `HISTSIZE=0; exit` to exit from the shell and clean the history of the current shell.

With the second one (`HISTFILE=`), a little shorter than all his variants (`HISTFILE=/dev/null`, `unset HISTFILE`... ), you will continue to have the *history* available in the current shell but it will not recordered when you will exit.

The *built-in* `help history` propose even

> **-c**        clear the history list by deleting all of the entries

---

In case you are using a *zsh shell* [you can see this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111777/66388) and the solution proposed.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following command is what I am looking for to clear history of temporary terminals:

```
unset HISTFILE
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).